# Grouping documents based on named and Lat ,long in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I wanted to group documents based on Name and Lat, Lang in Elastic Search.I explored the aggregations API but it gives  only a count for a specific criteria not the actual documents.Is there a way in which we can do this in Elastic Search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use nested aggregations - something like aggregate by name, _id. And use second query to get document by ids.

Comment: Thanks I will look up and try